Identifying negative cycles in Bellman-Ford Algorithm

As I opted for option 1 and 3 (-6, infinity),(-7, Infinity) and applied the Bellman-Ford algorithm for shortest path calculation, the calculation did not show any negative cycles after n’th steps for both the options(I might be wrong). Therefore is it valid to say that the value of “X” should be at least “-7” to avoid any negative cycles ?

I would run this code in debug mode to trace and confirm the findings.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/bellman-ford-algorithm

To determine whether the Bellman-Ford algorithm can be used without encountering negative cycles, we must look at the values of x that do not create a situation where the sum of the weights around a cycle is negative. The Bellman-Ford algorithm is capable of handling graphs with negative weights as long as there are no negative weight cycles reachable from the source vertex.
Given the graph in your image, we can analyze the cycles to see how x affects the total weight of each cycle:
Here are the potential cycles we need to check:

Cycle 0-1-3-2-0
Cycle 0-2-4-3-1-0
Cycle 1-3-4-2-1

We will check these cycles to see if their total weights can ever become negative with the edge weights involving x.

For cycle 0-1-3-2-0: Total weight = 6 + x + 5 + 3 = x + 14.
For cycle 0-2-4-3-1-0: Total weight = 5 + 4 + 5 + 1 + 6 = x + 21.
For cycle 1-3-4-2-1: Total weight = x + 5 + 4 + 3 = x + 12.

For there to be no negative cycles, all the cycle weights must be non-negative, which gives us:
x + 14 ≥ 0
x + 21 ≥ 0
x + 12 ≥ 0

The most restrictive of these is x + 12 ≥ 0, which implies x ≥ -12. So, for values of x that are greater than or equal to -12, the Bellman-Ford algorithm would not encounter any negative cycles and can be used to find the shortest path.
From your options, the ranges (-6, ∞) and (-7, ∞) are both subsets of [-12, ∞), which means they would both be valid ranges for x in which the Bellman-Ford algorithm can be used without encountering negative cycles. If x should be at least -7 to avoid negative cycles, this is incorrect because, according to the cycle analysis, x should be at least -12 to avoid negative cycles.

The only potential cycle I can find in this directed graph is (1-4-2-1) which involves edge x, which led me to (-7, inf) to avoid any negative cycles.
